# How to extract a number from a string in python

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a string coming from db, for example:

```
"any string coming from db[090876]"
```

I want to just fetch the numeric data and use it. In this case I just want `090876`.  How can I do it in Python/Django? I have tried with 're' but no luck.

Comment: Can you show what you tried?  It's not a terribly difficult problem once you understand regular expressions -- Perhaps seeing your attempt could help us to give you a better explanation of the concepts with regex that you're apparently missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [74]: import re

In [75]: re.findall('\d+',"any string coming from db[090876]")
Out[75]: ['090876']
```

or digits only between parens with `db` before it to be safe:

```
In [76]: re.findall('db\[(\d+)\]',"any string coming from db[090876]")
Out[76]: ['090876']
```

Comment: probably also want to include a db on the front of that 'db\\[(\d+\\)]'

Comment: @Hoopdady -- Thanks, I was just writing a more constrained example, it's added now.

Comment: Thanks root, but I need only 090876. using ur solution i ma getting this.                                                              In [3]: res = re.findall('db\[(\d+)\]',"any string coming from db[090876]")

In [4]: res
Out[4]: ['090876']

Comment: @sandeep --  `re.findall` returns a list, your can get the first element by index: `re.findall('db\[(\d+)\]',"any string coming from db[090876]")[0]`

Comment: You may wont to drop leading zeros: `'db\[0*(\d+)\]'`

Comment: May I ask why is there some [In|Out] [xx]: in front of each lines? (And why do they start with 74?)

Comment: @JeromeJ - Because I tested/typed it using [Ipython qtconsole](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/qtconsole.html) - it is not relevant to the code...

Answer (score 1):

```
x="any string coming from db[090876]"
word_ends=True
num_groups=[]
num=''
for i in x:

    try:
          int(i)
          num+=i
          word_ends=False

    except:

          if word_ends == False:
          num_groups.append(num)
          num=''
          word_ends=True
```